# "Error: Set breakpoints request timed out" while debugging Node in VS Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

While debugging Node in VS Code using the inspector protocol, I see this error. Breakpoints stay gray after setting them, but are still hit.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is due to a bug in Node, at least versions after v7.5. See this issue for progress: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/11589

The error is annoying but is safe to ignore. As I understand the bug, your breakpoints will stay gray until they are hit, but they will still be hit. The debugger reports a timeout because after it tells Node to add the breakpoint, Node sometimes doesn't respond for a long time.

Comment: This issue just started appearing this week (or last?). Maybe after a VS Code upgrade?
Am I the only one? How can I know where the issue is?
I have the latest VS Code (1.27.2) and node 10.5

Comment: This issue seems to reappear again and again

Comment: I am facing this issue too I have latest VSCode 1.31 and Node.JS 8.11.3

Comment: I am having same issue with 1.46.0 of VSC

Comment: Me too, issue is still there.